# Does "Romantic" have to do with Roman Empire or Romania?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading the biography of Mihai Eminescu, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihai_Eminescu, and in the first line it said that this guy was a romantic poet.

I didn't know what a romantic poet meant...was that he was a famed gentle lover? Then I scrolled down and it dawned on me this guy was from Romania...

When I clicked on romantic, however, it directed me to the page about some European enlightenment movement.

What does romantic mean in this context? Is Wikipedia directing me to the wrong link?

Comment: Did you read the very first sentence on the linked page ([Romanticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism))?

Comment: yes and how does that have to do with the kingdom of Romania?

Comment: Generally, neither one. Rome was great for a long time in fact, and for a much longer time in fantasy. So lots of things got named for it. Some stuck. _Romania, roman à clef, romanesque, romanesco, romance languages, romance, romanticism, romanization, romano cheese,_ et very copious cetera.

Comment: @MathNewb It doesn't, but it explains what *Romantic* refers to.

Comment: Capitalization makes a huge difference here! Since you failed to quote Wikipedia with the right capitalization, I'm voting to close this question as Unclear What You Are Asking.

Comment: Does the English translation of the Chinese story "Romance of Three Kingdoms" refer to a Romanian or Roman story? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_of_the_Three_Kingdoms

Answer (score 6):

*Romantic* in literary studies refers to Romanticism, a term applied retrospectively to a movement which in a wide variety of forms dominated European literature and arts from the late 18th to the late 19th century. The term had been around since at least the early seventeenth century to refer to mediaeval *romance* and the quality of fancy unrestrained by reality or reason associated with that body of literature; it was applied to the Romantic poets because they consciously rejected Enlightenment classicism:

> ... they discussed dreams, dramatic illusion, the limits of Classicism and Reason, and the dynamic nature of the Imagination. Remembered childhood, unrequited love, and the exiled hero were constant themes. [...] Romanticism expressed an unending revolt against classical form, conservative morality, authoritarian government, personal insincerity, and human moderation. —Margaret Drabble, *The Oxford Companion to English Literature*

In Germany and the subject nations of Eastern Europe the movement was also closely associated with nationalism and the quest for a national identity in older native forms which antedated the international Englightenment style of the colonial powers.

Answer (score 1):

It says that he was *a Romantic poet*, the capital R is a first hint that it's not just the word *romantic*.

The reason why *Romantic* is linked to a page about the *Romantic era* is because that's exactly what they are referring to.

Ie, by *Romantic poet* they are referring to a *poet of the Romantic era* (writing in the style associated with that time period).

Answer (score 1):

Well, [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=romance) says "romance" comes from:

> c.1300, "a story, written or recited, of the adventures of a knight,
>   hero, etc.," often one designed principally for entertainment," from
>   Old French romanz "verse narrative" (Modern French roman), originally
>   an adverb, "in the vernacular language," from Vulgar Latin *romanice
>   scribere* "to write in a Romance language" (one developed from Latin
>   instead of Frankish), from Latin Romanicus "of or in the Roman style,"
>   from Romanus "Roman" (see Roman).

So the words based on "romance" are distinguishing between Latin and "Frankish", though along a convoluted path.  The path mainly threads through heroic French literature.

Of course, "romanticism" (as described elsewhere) is a somewhat later term, but it comes from the fact that "romance" was associated with nature, in a reaction to the Industrial Revolution and scientific "rationalism".